# Spring Data compare 2 date ranges

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data, hql

I need to compare one date range for bookings if they are available
eg client sends 21-03-2018 to 25-03-2018   , server returns all Bookings available that are in not inside that range from the database.

```
List<Booking> findByStarDateBetween(Date start, Date end);

List<Booking> findByEndDateBetween(Date start, Date end);
```

do i have to go for a custom query?

```
db table

Booking
int id;
Date startDate;
Date endDate;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [join the conditions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html). Hence, your code would be:

```
List<Booking> results = findByStartDateBeforeAndEndDateAfter(startDate, endDate);
```

Hope that helps. If not, please leave a comment.

Comment: +1 for the join conditions tip, although lets say there is a booking for 22 to 29 and in the database there is a booking for 21 to 30 it will overlap it. I am looking for something like findByStarDateBetweenNotAndEndDateBetweenNot(Date start,Date end)

Comment: You could, I don't know, try it out?